# Inject class in other class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I've got a `Tag` class and a `TagCollection` class to store multiple tags. Now the `TagRepository` class needs to construct a new `Tag` object to return. But when I try to create a new `Tag` inside the `TagRepository` it returns an error:

> Tag is not defined

This is how I include all the classes in the main JavaScript files:

```
const Tag = require('./class/Tag.js');
const TagCollection = require('./class/TagCollection.js');
const TagRepository = require('./repository/TagRepository.js');
```

How do we usually deal with this? I could just include the needed classes inside the constructor of the class that requires them. But that seems messy when I have to include multiple classes.

The only other solution I could think of is making the needed classes global, reading online it seems like that is considered bad practice. Below I've included all the classes

**Tag.js**

```
module.exports = class Tag {
  constructor() {
    this.id;
    this.name;
  }

  setId(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

**TagCollection.js**

```
module.exports = class TagCollection {
  constructor() {
    this.tags = [];
  }

  addTag(tag) {
    this.tags.push(tag);   
  }

  setTags(tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }

  getTags(tags) {
    return this.tags;
  }
}
```

**TagRepository.js**

```
module.exports = class TagRepository {
  constructor(conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
  }

  getAll(callback) {
    let tempTagCollection = new TagCollection;

    this.conn.query(`SELECT \`id\`, \`name\` FROM \`tag\` WHERE 1`, function (error, tags) {
      tags.forEach((tag) => {
        //Create single tag 
        let tempTag = new Tag;

        //Set properties
        tempTag.setName(tag.name);
        tempTag.setId(tag.id);

        //Add single tag to collection
        tempTagCollection.addTag(tempTag);
      })

      callback(tempTagCollection);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could provide code I think it would help us understand the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code? You probably want to require Tag.js inside TagRepository.js if you are using it there.

Comment: @NTR I've added the code

Comment: @sn3p I've included the code now

Comment: You should put the `const Tag = require('./class/Tag.js');
const TagCollection = require('./class/TagCollection.js');` lines inside the *TagRepository.js* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only other solution I could think of is making the needed classes global, reading online it seems like that is considered bad practice.

You're right, making global variables should be avoided as much as possible as it promotes brittle and hard to debug code.

You can think of each file as a module. I personally like to keep one file per class, so I can treat the class itself as a module. In each module, you should `require` every class that you depend on.

So I'll use a classic Animal/Cat/Dog example:

```
//Animal.js
module.exports = class Animal { ... }

//Cat.js
const Animal = require('./Animal');
class Cat extends Animal { ... }

//Dog
const Animal = require('./Dog');
class Dog extends Animal { ... }
```

In NodeJS, even though both `Cat` & `Dog` requires `Animal`, *Animal.js* is only ever executed once. So each module that requires `Animal` will obtain the same `Animal` class.

> I could just include the needed classes inside the constructor of the class that requires them.

I would also avoid doing this. Using `require` in a constructor, even though a `require`'d file will only execute the file the first time it has been required, it still goes through the node file resolution algorithm which is an expensive process and may cause performance bottlenecks. Generally it is best to have your `require` statements outside of constructors or functions. Keep them at the top of the file, where all the requires will run once when the application loads.

> As you can now see inside the TagRepository it requires two classes, the Tag and TagCollection class how would I go about this?

Inside TagRepository.js you just need to simply have 2 include statements, one for each file, see below.

```
const Tag = require('./Tag');
const TagCollection = require('./TagCollection.js');

// Both Tag and TagCollection is now usable

class TagRepository { ... }
```

Further reading on NodeJS modules can be found here

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Comment: Thanks you! As you can now see inside the `TagRepository` it requires two classes, the Tag and TagCollection class how would I go about this? Considering I can only extend from one class.

Comment: Inside `TagRepository` you would have 2 `require` statements... I'll update my answer as it will be easier to format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'require' every class you need in every file you need it, so unlike (for example) PHP you can't just require everything once per program.

Comment: I see, where would I require the other external classes inside a class? I just learned from the other answer that it really isn't ideal to include a require inside the constructor.

Comment: You include everything at the top of the file, in every file you need it.